# Python Tornado serving of AngularJS App and initial route from AngularApp heading back to server

Tags: angularjs, tornado

I am having an issue where the initial href request that should be handled by ng-route is instead routed to the backend server.  After that initial request,  the same href would route properly within my app using my route config.

My app/index.html is being served by a Tornado backend server which deals with the initial ( non-spa) login page and mult-platform login support.  Once authenticated, my tornado server writes app/index.html.   How does angular decide when to route to the server and when not to?  Any suggestions on where to look to debug this?

Comment: Can you give us some examples of the hrefs you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you initialize your angular app and setup routes angular is ready to serve client side routes.

```
//index.html page
app.config( function ( $routeProvider,$locationProvider ) {
  $routeProvider
    .when( '/this', { templateUrl: 'this.html' } )
    .when( '/that', { templateUrl: 'that.html' } )
    .when( '/other', { templateUrl: 'other.html' } )
    .otherwise( { redirectTo: 'this' } );

     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});


app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function ( $scope, $location ) {
    $scope.location = $location;
});
```

---

Depending on how you setup your routing links like:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>{{location.path()}}</div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/this">This</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/that">That</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/other">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

Would be client side routes(fiddle example).

If you enable:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Then you can do stuff like:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="this">This</a></li>
 <li><a href="that">That</a></li>
 <li><a href="other">Other</a></li>
</ul>
```

Would be client side routes[(fiddle example 2)](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/kfM6e/).

[Angular $route Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route)

Comment: I have the config setup as you ( and the docs ) subscribe.  Including the html5mode AND the routes work as prescribed EXCEPT for the initial route request after the app has loaded.  So unfortunately, pointing me  to the docs on routing and listing the example of using the routes unfortunately doesn't help me.  The only thing I would add is that there maybe other server side redirects happening prior to the app/index.html being returned.  These redirects are for oauth/oauth2 login authentications.